# Is there any way that I can insert columns in loop in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, slice

code in octave:

```
 for j = 0:5
        k(:, end+1) = (X1.^j)
```

Code in numpy:

```
 for j in range(0,5):
        k[?]=np.power(X1,j)
```

so here I want to add columns to k-array, suppose k=(10,1) dim and I want to make it (10,5) dim in the loop, above is code in octave and slicing is pretty much straight but is there any way that I can slice K and insert columns for every iteration. let me know if anyone helps clear this slicing better.

Comment: what is `l` in your code?

Comment: Oh okay I forgot to edit.... its j

Comment: Did you want to fill entire column `j` with `j^2`?

Comment: yes...take it as any function there I just want to insert columns in the loop considering any mathematical function on the right-hand side. how do slice it?

Comment: Well, you should avoid looping with numpy as much as possible. It also depends on your mathematical operation, I would advise posting the full question so we can help better. See if you can get ideas from the answer I posted.

Comment: Please fix your code. `k[:,:j]` is not valid syntax.

Comment: yes, I know, but cant I slice a np array in the loop for adding column or row for every iteration?

Comment: While this works in MATLAB/octave, is it really the most efficient approach?  Compared, for example, to starting with a large enough `k`, and assigning values.

Comment: In `numpy` we prefer starting with a list, and repeatedly using lisr `append`, and then making the array at the end.  It's faster.

Comment: A possible duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/q/45852502/901925

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?:

```
np.tile(np.arange(5)**2,10).reshape(-1,5)
```

output:

```
[[ 0  1  4  9 16]
 [ 0  1  4  9 16]
 [ 0  1  4  9 16]
 [ 0  1  4  9 16]
 [ 0  1  4  9 16]
 [ 0  1  4  9 16]
 [ 0  1  4  9 16]
 [ 0  1  4  9 16]
 [ 0  1  4  9 16]
 [ 0  1  4  9 16]]
```

but if you insist on doing it with loops which is a BAD idea:

```
k = np.zeros((10,1), dtype=int)
print(k)
for j in np.arange(5):
  k = np.hstack((k,[[j**2]]*k.shape[0]))

[[ 0  0  1  4  9 16]
 [ 0  0  1  4  9 16]
 [ 0  0  1  4  9 16]
 [ 0  0  1  4  9 16]
 [ 0  0  1  4  9 16]
 [ 0  0  1  4  9 16]
 [ 0  0  1  4  9 16]
 [ 0  0  1  4  9 16]
 [ 0  0  1  4  9 16]
 [ 0  0  1  4  9 16]]
```

Comment: alright. I want to add one column for every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @kshitijjagatkar glad it helped. Please accept to close. Thank you.

Comment: I did not get brother what should I accept. This is my first question on this

Comment: yeah... did it pal. sorry for the inconvenience I'm new here